# Why is there no electric dipole term in the Hyperfine Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, dipole

I have been looking a several discussions of hyperfine structure. (For example: [here](http://cua.mit.edu/8.421_S06/Chapter4_5.pdf) and in the explanation for eq. 2.1 [here](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.49.31)

It seems that the hyperfine interaction can be explained almost entirely in terms of the magnetic dipole interaction between electron and nucleus and the electric quadrupole interaction between electron and nucleus.

Why is there no electric dipole term?

I sense that this arises from some semi-obvious property of the electron or nucleus, but I can't seem to figure out what this property might be.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the nucleus nor the electrons form electric dipoles of any kind - the electron is a point charge, a monopole; the nucleus contains only one type of charge, the positive protons (and the electrically neutral neutrons). There is no scope for electric dipole interactions between the nucleus and electrons.

The nucleus can still have an electric quadrupole moment, based on the proton distribution (see [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elequad.html#c1)). The magnetic dipole moment of course comes from the spin of the nucleons, and the electron.

It may be added that it is possible for a nucleus to have a fleetingly small momentary dipole moment, based on the arrangement of the positively charged up and negatively charged down quarks that make up the nucleons. This will probably produce a very (very) weak effect compared to the magnitude of hyperfine splitting, considering the fact that no permanent dipole moments have been observed. There's a little bit more about these internal dipole moments [here](http://www.bnl.gov/edm/).

Comment: Your initial claim is morally true, but not quite true technically. It is possible, theoretically, for there to be a nonzero [electron electric dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_electric_dipole_moment), and indeed the SM predicts a nonzero (but exceedingly small) value. Precision experiments are underway to check whether it's a bigger value (as predicted by beyond-the-SM theories), but those effects are only visible in a dedicated high-precision experiment (with a negative result so far).

Answer (score 1):

Nuclei have a very [small electric dipole moment](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCgQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphysics.usask.ca%2F~pywell%2Fp452%2FLectures%2FLecture-10.pdf&ei=GPRNVYj9NI66uATO84GQDw&usg=AFQjCNGMwqxl85RJFKbPaRiE0Sn1kq7LuQ&sig2=QFsKp9O7iJkipaWF5gvGhg&bvm=bv.92885102,d.c2E). However, they can have a significant quadrupole moment, which influences hyperfine structure. You can refer to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfine_structure#Electric_quadrupole) article to get a quick understanding of the latter.

Comment: Note that your first link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Because the interaction between the electric dipole moment and the electric field is a Parity and Time violating interaction.

Usually the interactions that violate symmetries are ignored, because they have not been measured yet.

However, the electric dipole moment (and magnetic quadrupole moment) are the cutting-edge target in the field of precision spectroscopy.
The measurable values are expected in particle physics mode beyond the standard model.

The following one is an example aiming to search for the electric dipole moment
i)electron: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-018-0599-8
ii)nucleus: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.161601